# which one is more computationally intensive?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-complexity

Taking the latest available algorithms into account, which one is more computationally difficult: inversion of a matrix or calculation of its eigenvalues?

I have developed a formula in applied mathematics that requires matrix inversion. A previously published formula demands all the eigenvalues of the matrix. I would like to somehow demonstrate that my formula is better. Could you give me some inputs? Thanks

Comment: Look at the algorithms for calculating the inverse of a matrix and its eigenvalues and check which ones are more numerically complex. Also, the structure of the matrix may play an important role.